# Visual Studio 2010 Shell Package installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, add-in

I have created a visual studio 2010 add-in using the "Visual Studio Package" template which comes with the VS 2010 SDK. I can see the add-in operate with F5.

How do I permanently deploy this as an add-in to the Add-in Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just run the .vsix file that is in the output folder (bin\Debug or bin\Release). That will install the extension to your "main" instance of Visual Studio.

By default, when you press F5, your extension runs in the "Experimental Instance" of Visual Studio which is isolated from your main instance.